# Python-pptx: How to update chart data for the second chart, if two chart are present on same slide

Tags: python-3.x, charts, python-pptx

I want to update chart data for my existing powerpoint presentation slide, having 2 charts, namely a Bar Chart and a Pie Chart. I am successfully able to update the bar chart as it was first element on my content slide placeholder. Now I am not sure how to update the second chart i.e Pie chart on same slide.
My code is like as below:

```
prs = Presentation("Request_Slide.pptx")
slide = prs.slides[0]
for shape in slide.placeholders:
     print('%d %s' %(shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))
```

with above I got below response:

```
0 Title 1
1 Content Placeholder 5
```

With help of this i managed to navigate to my first chart on Slide[0] and updated its chart data however i am struggling to navigate to second chart present in content placeholder. Any suggestions would be of great help and thanks in advance.

Comment: A placeholder is just a special category of shape and not all shapes are placeholders. Try using `for shape in slide.shapes` instead and see how you can identify the second chart that way. It could be the second chart was added as a "free-standing" shape of its own. As far as I know, a placeholder cannot directly hold two charts.

Comment: @Scanny: With Slide.shapes I got all the shapes, but What I found that I am not able to access shapes index as per below code:

 prs = Presentation("A-Sample_slide.pptx")
slide1 = prs.slides[0]

for shape in slide1.shapes:
     print('%d %s' % (prs.slides.index(shape), shape.name))

Instead I got error message like: "    raise ValueError('%s is not in slide collection' % slide)
ValueError: <pptx.shapes.graphfrm.GraphicFrame object at 0x0000019943E14308> is not in slide collection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve using listing the shape name index and using shape index to update chart data by using below code:

```
 list_shape_names = [shape.name for shape in slide.shapes]

    if shape_name not in list_shape_names:
        shape_index = None
    else:
        shape_index = list_shape_names.index(shape_name)
```

But do take care while passing shape_name as it will be case sensitive.